# How to get the index of element from contains function of array in vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net

i have a list of large number of string elements in array 
and i am using contains function to check if it contains that element. it is working fine. Now i want to get to know the index/position of element.
suppose the array is

```
dim s as string() = {"first", "second","third"}
```

and the string

```
dim l as string = "third"
```

method

```
dim b as boolean = s.Contains(l, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```

flag

```
if (b) Then
messagebox.show("It exists") 
end if
```

above array is just an example. original array consists of 7690 entries and each entry is written in utf-8 and indexOf function is not giving any result

Comment: If the array does contains your string, it also should be able to give you the string's  index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should consider using a [List(Of T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) when writing in VB.Net.

The List class provides an [List(Of T).IndexOf Method (T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You can do something like this :

```
Dim index As Integer = YourList.IndexOf(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for the [IndexOf function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b2fz03t(v=vs.110).aspx).

UPDATE: I came up with the following quick example that encoded a string similar to your example string into UTF-8 and it still works:

```
    Dim s As String() = {"first", "second", "third", "four", "five", "six"}

    For Each tempString As String In s
        Dim bytes As Byte() = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(tempString)
        tempString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes)
    Next

    Dim l As String = "six"
    Debug.Print(Array.IndexOf(s, l))
```

Comment: sort of. indexOf function doesn't work. I am currently working with a array of 7690 entries and each entry/string is in utf-8 format